# How to transition z-index?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

https://jsfiddle.net/vaf6nv36/1/

Can the balloons image slowly transition over the apple image?

I think that I need more transition parameters, or I should use opacity?

Can someone help me?

HTML:

```
<div class="img1">

</div>

<div class="img2">
                    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img1, .img2{
   border: 1px solid black;
   transition: 1s;
   position: absolute;
}

.img1{
    left: 25%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url(http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/balloons-photography-vintage-wallpaper-1.jpg);
   }

.img2{
  right: 25%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-image:  url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c1/7b/15/c17b150e93c4e9c50d963b076484bee7--apple-wallpaper-iphone-wallpaper.jpg);
}

.img1:hover{
       z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Opacity is probably the way to go.

Comment: What would a transition on z-index do? It's either in front of it, or it's not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although theoretically you *can* transition `z-index`, it wouldn't make much sense, i.e. would not result in the crossfade effect which you obviously are looking for: `z-index` values are integers, which - when you change them in the smallest possible steps (integers, no commas) -  results in states either before the other one OR behind the other one - no transitional "half states" in between. If you want to do a kind of continuous crossfade between two elements, you should use a transition on `opacity`.

In your particular case, since your DIVs are not directly above each other, but only overlap each other, you can solve that by having a second `DIV` identical to `img2` (I called its class `.img3`), but with `z-index: 0` and this CSS rule:

```
.img1:hover + .img2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This will fade out img2, but still show img3, which however is *behind*  img1, creating the impression of a transition between img1 and img2.

https://jsfiddle.net/2a2epLfv/1/

```css
.img1,
.img2,
.img3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

.img1 {
  left: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/balloons-photography-vintage-wallpaper-1.jpg);
}

.img2,
.img3 {
  right: 20%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c1/7b/15/c17b150e93c4e9c50d963b076484bee7--apple-wallpaper-iphone-wallpaper.jpg);
}

.img2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.img3 {
  z-index: 0;
}

.img1:hover+.img2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img1"></div>
<div class="img2"></div>
<div class="img3"></div>
```

Comment: `You can't transition z-index` This is wrong, z-index is a valid property to apply a transition to.

Comment: @Johannes Yes, I read your whole answer. The part I referenced is still incorrect. It's odd that you said it and then went on to contradict yourself by describing how transitioning `z-index` works.

Comment: @TylerH I wrote that it doesn't make sense, meaning it wouldn't result in the crossfade effect which the OP wanted to have. Anyway, i found a solution for him. But I'll add something so that everybody can be happy...

Comment: One valid use case for transitioning `z-index` is when you simply want to delay the value change (e.g. after finishing an opacity transition).  You can use the `transition-delay` setting for such use cases.  This offers a CSS-based approach with having to get into javascript timers.

Comment: @nextgentech that's actually what I just needed to "transition" z-index for.. I wanted it to happen after a certain `transition-delay`.

Answer (score 4):

I fear z-index transition only makes the element pass step by step through every layer. To make a nice effect you need to combine it with opacity transition and scale / position transition. The fiddle to show you the idea:

```css
.img1, .img2{

  border: 1px solid black;
    transition: 1s;
    position: absolute;
}

.img1{
    left: 25%;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-image: url(http://cdn.pcwallart.com/images/balloons-photography-vintage-wallpaper-1.jpg);
}

.img2{
    right: 25%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-image:  url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c1/7b/15/c17b150e93c4e9c50d963b076484bee7--apple-wallpaper-iphone-wallpaper.jpg);
}

.img1:hover{
    animation: fronte 1s linear forwards; 
}

@keyframes fronte {
  from { z-index: 0; transform: scale(0.9); opacity: 0.5; }
  to { z-index: 4; transform: scale(1.1); opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="img1">
</div>
<div class="img2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the trick I used.

```css
.minus{animation:move 2s;animation-fill-mode:forwards;animation-delay:2s;}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0 {z-index:1;opacity:1}
  50% {opacity:0}
  100% { z-index:-1;opacity:1}
}
@keyframes move {
  0 {z-index:1;opacity:1}
  50% {opacity:0}
  100% {z-index:-1;opacity:1}
}

#main{background:red;width:100vw;height:100vh;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;opacity:.9}
.minus{position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px;z-index:1;color:#000}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<div class="minus">FADE</div>
```