# Z-index change within @keyframes animation causing a pop

Tags: css, keyframe

I would like each `<div>` to stay on screen for 8 sec before it fades out.

Also I would like them to fade into each other, opposed to fading to black and then the other fades in.

This works great thanks to @giovannipds except for a pop and not on screen for 8 sec. If you remove the z-index change it transitions clean.

```css
.slider {
        line-height: 1.5;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
      }
      .slide {
        padding: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .slide,.slide a {
        color: #fff;
      }
      .slide1 {
        animation: fade 8s infinite;
        background: red;
      }
      .slide2 {
        animation: fade2 8s infinite;
        background: blue;
      }
      @keyframes fade
      {
        0% { opacity: 1 ; z-index: 2; }
        33.333% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1; }
        66.666% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1; }
        100% { opacity: 1; z-index: 2; }
      }
      @keyframes fade2
      {
        0% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1; }
        33.333% { opacity: 1; z-index: 2; }
        66.666% { opacity: 1; z-index: 2; }
        100% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1; }
      }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="//www.globo.com" target="_blank">Globo.com</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="//www.lovemondays.com.br" target="_blank">Love Mondays</a></li>
          <li><a href="//www.hotmail.com" target="_blank">Hotmail</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46384969/5641669

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I was recently confronted with the same POP problem and I managed to solve it by separating the **image** and **caption** markup on each slide and by assigning separate cross-fade animations to each:

- **image** animation (*with* `opacity` but *without* `z-index`) => just like `fade` and `fade2` in the snippet above but *without* `z-index`; this actually solved the POP
- **caption** animation (*with both* `opacity` and `z-index`) => just like `fade` and `fade2` in the snippet above, this would address links or any other HTML you might want on top of image