# Animating z-index

Tags: html, css

I have this [page](https://4309.co.uk) and want to apply this to it.

```css
.contact {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  float: right;
}

.contact:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 70px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 70px solid red;
}

.contact {
  animation: fish 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fish {
  0% {
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    right: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    right: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  75% {
    right: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

.box {height: 50px; width 100px; background-color: black; margin: auto; transform: rotate(90deg);}
```

```html
<div class="contact"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

The problem is that various other elements on the page have different z-index and I want to send it behind some and in front of others. Can I animate the z-index, as it were? For example 5s into animation z-index 1 would apply, 10s in z-index 3 would apply.

Comment: Yes, `z-index` is animatable but may not give you the effect you are after. Something is either on top of another or it's not....have you tried this?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks. Example please. Think fish going behind Reed and in front of next Reed...

Comment: No... **you** should attempt to code this....not us.... http://zomigi.com/blog/css3-transitions-and-z-index/

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384799/how-to-transition-z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's done exactly as you'd expect. Just add `z-index` into your animation keyframes like so:

```css
.contact {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  float: right;
}

.contact:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 70px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 70px solid red;
}

.contact {
  animation: fish 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes fish {
  0% {
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    right: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    right: 200px;
    top: 200px;
    z-index:100;
  }
  75% {
    right: 0px;
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

.box {height: 50px; width 100px; background-color: black; margin: auto; transform: rotate(90deg);}
```

```html
<div class="contact"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```